# How to keep a button inside an image when screen gets smaller

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to keep a button inside an image. But when the screen gets smaller the button leaves the image field and just floats around. How could I fix it?

```css
.slider-button {
  background: gold;   
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #262626;
  border: none;
  padding: 22px 72px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
}

.slider-img {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<img src = "https://www.mundiario.com/media/mundiario/images/2019/10/02/2019100220032812226.png" / class="slider-img"> 
<button class="slider-button">Press W to win</button>
```

Comment: Is there a wrapper div you have not included? You HTML& CSS do not match up?

Comment: Should the button always be in the middle of the image?  
if not, what should happen to its position when changing the screen size?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.slider-button {
  background: gold;   
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #262626;
  border: none;
  padding: 22px 72px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<img src = "https://www.mundiario.com/media/mundiario/images/2019/10/02/2019100220032812226.png" /> 
<button class="slider-button">Press W to win</button>
```

you have to use like this ".slider-button", "img" in css and over all it's working fine. I have look your code.

Answer (score -1):

Just put the button inside of your image container:

```
<img src = "https://www.mundiario.com/media/mundiario/images/2019/10/02/2019100220032812226.png" class="slider-img"> 
<button class="slider-button">Press W to win</button>
</img>
```

Comment: Images **can't have contents**.